# Duration between the current row and the next one using Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

**Trip**

```
id,timestamp
1008,2003-11-03 15:00:31
1008,2003-11-03 15:02:38
1008,2003-11-03 15:03:04
1008,2003-11-03 15:18:00
1009,2003-11-03 22:00:00
1009,2003-11-03 22:02:53
1009,2003-11-03 22:03:44 
1009,2003-11-14 10:00:00
1009,2003-11-14 10:02:02
1009,2003-11-14 10:03:10
```

**Using Pandas:**

```
trip['time_diff'] = np.where(trip['id'] == trip['id'].shift(-1),
                             trip['timestamp'].shift(-1) - trip['timestamp']/1000,
                             None)

trip['time_diff'] = pd.to_numeric(trip['time_diff'])
```

I did this operation in Pyspark but nothing works, it's been a week that I program with spark then I still have trouble using the window.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

my_window = Window.partition('id').orderBy('timestamp').rowsBetween(0, 1)

timeFmt = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

time_diff = (F.unix_timestamp(trip.timestamp, format=timeFmt).cast("long")  - 
             F.unix_timestamp(trip.timestamp, format=timeFmt).over(my_window).cast("long")) 

trip = trip.withColumn('time_diff', time_diff)
```

I wonder if that's the way to do it!! If not how to translate this operation into Pyspark?

[delta_time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jj1b3.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEYfV.png)

**the result should look like**

```
id, timestamp, diff_time
1008, 2003-11-03 15:00:31, 127
1008, 2003-11-03 15:02:38, 26
1008, 2003-11-03 15:03:04, 896
1008, 2003-11-03 15:18:00, None
1009, 2003-11-03 22:00:00, 173
1009, 2003-11-03 22:02:53, 51
1009, 2003-11-03 22:03:44, 956776
1009, 2003-11-14 10:00:00, .....
1009, 2003-11-14 10:02:02, .....
1009, 2003-11-14 10:03:10, .....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `lead` function and calculate the time difference. The following gives what you want:

```
val interdf = spark.sql("select id, timestamp, lead(timestamp) over (partition by id order by timestamp) as next_ts from data")
interdf.createOrReplaceTempView("interdf")
spark.sql("select id, timestamp, next_ts, unix_timestamp(next_ts) - unix_timestamp(timestamp) from interdf").show()
```

If you want to avoid spark-sql, you can do the same by importing the relevant functions

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lead
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val window = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("timestamp")
```

Relevant Python code:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import abs

window = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("timestamp")

diff = col("timestamp").cast("long") - lead("timestamp", 1).over(window).cast("long")
df = df.withColumn("diff", diff)
df = df.withColumn('diff', abs(df.diff))
```

#### Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can not understand why the timestamps are not ordered even with an orderBy. And also I cheated to have the positive difference adding abs (), I don't know if it's the best way to make it !!

Comment: @adilblanco Your edit was rejected by a couple mods but I edited my answer to include your Python code. Sorry I totally missed that you were working in Python. To answer your question, the timestamps are indeed ordered, but for each id because that's what the partition is based on. Also, my code had `lead(timestamp) - timestamp`. Your code is `timestamp - lead(timestamp` and that's why you're getting negative values.